# Badly Placed ()'s Error within Python Script

Tags: python

Running a python script within Linux Emacs shell and keep getting the error 'badly placed ()'s

not sure where there problem originates but here is my script

```
inputFile = open('ieh.sgdc', 'r')
outputFile = open('riskAreas.txt', 'w')

cdc_txt = inputFile.readlines(SIZE)
SIZE = 639


for line in inputFile:
   if 'clock' in cdc_txt:
     if '-name' in cdc_txt:
         outputFile.write("clock = ")
         outputFile.append(line[12:8])
         continue

    elif reset in line:
      if '-name' in cdc_txt:
        outputFile.write("reset = ")
      outputFile.append(line[12:8])
      continue

      if '-value' in cdc_txt:
         outputFile.write("reset = ")
      outputFile.append(line[12:8])
     continue

    else:
         break 


cdc_txt.next()

inputFile.close()
outputFile.close()
```

Comment: This code is not indented properly.

Comment: indent if block after for

Comment: Like @khelwood said, having broken indentation will cause all sorts of grief in python and might make it look like you've got problems elsewhere. Your parentheses are fine, just fix your indentation.

Comment: In python there are no opening and closing braces `{ }` so the way it determines scope is by indentation.

Comment: Sorry, very new to stack overflow. I fixed the indentation to reflect how it appears within the shell. Are there more indentation errors?  @emsimpson92

Comment: I'll post an answer with proper indentation.

Comment: If you're using emacs, it should be helping—almost forcing—you to keep the indentation straight. Don't fight against it.

Comment: If you're still having trouble with indentation after learning to use your editor, try installing `black` and running it against your code. If it wants to change anything in your indentation, it may be wrong about the correct answer, but it's right that you got something wrong.

Comment: Are you trying to make use of your `SIZE` variable before you declared it?

Comment: Good catch @khelwood. You'll need to swap those two lines OP

Answer (score 1):

in your code

```
cdc_txt = inputFile.readlines(SIZE)
SIZE = 639
```

you are using SIZE variable before declare it. it should be;

```
SIZE = 639
cdc_txt = inputFile.readlines(SIZE)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the proper indentation:

```
inputFile = open('ieh.sgdc', 'r')
outputFile = open('riskAreas.txt', 'w')

SIZE = 639
cdc_txt = inputFile.readlines(SIZE)


for line in inputFile:
  if 'clock' in cdc_txt:
    if '-name' in cdc_txt:
      outputFile.write("clock = ")
      outputFile.append(line[12:8])
      continue

    elif reset in line:
      if '-name' in cdc_txt:
        outputFile.write("reset = ")
        outputFile.append(line[12:8])
        continue

      if '-value' in cdc_txt:
        outputFile.write("reset = ")
        outputFile.append(line[12:8])
        continue

    else:
      break 


cdc_txt.next()

inputFile.close()
outputFile.close()
```

I'm not really sure what you're trying to do here, so you might need to modify your indentation for this section based on your desired logic.

```
    if '-name' in cdc_txt:
      outputFile.write("clock = ")
      outputFile.append(line[12:8])
      continue

    elif reset in line:
      if '-name' in cdc_txt:
        outputFile.write("reset = ")
        outputFile.append(line[12:8])
        continue

      if '-value' in cdc_txt:
        outputFile.write("reset = ")
        outputFile.append(line[12:8])
        continue
```

**keep in mind that it is important that you use either tabs or spaces. You cannot mix and match the two or you will run into more errors.**

Comment: Still running into the same error. Emacs doesn't really specify where the error line is placed. The indentation of the if/else statements doesn't seem to change anything as I have updated the logic.

Comment: Try using a different editor to see if it tells you what line the problem is occurring on. Vim or nano should do.

Answer (score 0):

"Badly placed ()s" is a Csh error message. You are using something else than what you are saying in your question (which doesn't make much sense anyway; Emacs is not a shell).

This could happen e.g. if you tried

```sh
bash$ tcsh

horror% func () {   # trying to run a Bourne shell function definition
Badly placed ()'s

horror% inputFile = open('ieh.sgdc', 'r')   # trying to run Python code
Badly placed ()'s.
```

But of course, this makes little sense. Put your Python code in a file and run it with

```
horror% python filename.py   # works EVEN in tcsh, and on Windows!!! (sometimes...)
```

Tangentially, you'll probably want to abandon this moribund shell from the 1980s. But trying to run Python code in the shell, or Lisp code in Basic, or Haskell code in your assembler, will never work anyway.

```
horror% exit

bash$ sudo rm /bin/tcsh /bin/csh
```